# More clarity about buit-in, basic and primitive data type?

Tags: types, primitive, built-in

I have seen some definitions about **basic data type**, **primitive data type**, and **built-in data type**. But I am not sure yet, how can I say a data type is basic or primitive or even primitive basic!
Is there any good definition to help specify type of a data type in this way?

Wikipedia says that primitive data type consists of basic data type and built-in data type. [foldoc.org](http://foldoc.org/type) says : "*Some types are primitive - built-in to the language, with no visible internal structure*".

I am really confused!

Comment: The meanings of these terms are likely to vary depending on the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing from the book of Michael L. Scott, *Programming Language Pragmatics*, section 7.1.1 (The definition of Types), p.322:

> There are at least three ways to think about types, which we may call the *denotational*, *constructive*, and *abstraction-based* points of view. [...]
>   From the constructive point of view, a type is either one of a small collection of *built-in* types (integer, character, Boolean, real, etc.; also called *primitive* or *predefined* types), or a *composite* type created by applying a type *constructor* (`record`, `array`, `set` etc.) to one or more simpler types. (This use of the term "constructor" is unrelated to the initialization functions of C++ and Java. [...]

Therefore, from a theoretical POV, those terms (*primitive*, *built-in*, *predefined* - I will add *basic* too) are all more or less synonyms and they are all understandable in contrast with *composite* types, which are built from them using, possibly in a recursive manner, some kind of "operation on types" (*an array of char*, *a collection of pointers*, *a list of records each consisting of a float and a string*, etc.)

I agree with @KeithThompson that from a practical POV each language will use (some of) these terms assigning very specific meanings to them, thus you would have to browse the particular language specification to know what is meant in that context.

Comment: A primitive data type may be not implemented (built-in, from theoretical POV) but the primitive type are built in normally (from practical POV).  
Built-in has a clear definition: implemented in programming language itself. Then it depends on implementation, but thats not true about basic and primitive.

Comment: Well I think you are looking for coherence where there's none. AFAIK, as that was the point I tried to make, there is neither a strong (mathematical) definition nor a widely accepted one of all these terms in technical literature.

Comment: To add more info: in the excerpt I cited, built-in, primitive and predefined types are considered synonyms, but as an example of a different terminological choice I can cite Stroustrup (The C++ programming language, 2nd ed., p.70), where he calls bools, ints, chars, etc, *fundamental types*, whereas he reserves the term *built-in types* for all the types that are not *user-defined* (like classes, enums,...), thus according to him a pointer to an int is *built-in* (but not *fundamental*)!

Comment: See also, as another example of lack of coeherence ***across*** different languages/authors the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html). Here the types are either ***primitive*** or ***reference*** types. Just another convention!

Comment: And as a yet another POV, [here is a link](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1) to the relevant section of Lua reference manual. As you can see, Lua authors speak of **basic** types.

Comment: Thank you. Then, unfortunately there is not a strong definition in type theory for **primitive** and **basic**.

Answer (score 1):

A **built-in data type** is one that is available in the language and not added from a library or the code you write. Typically, this is the case for `int` or `string`.

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) says: "Opinions vary as to whether a built-in type that is not basic should be considered 'primitive'", the definition of a **primitive data type** is not really clear. In my personal opinion, a **primitive data type** is the same as a **basic data type**, i. e. one that has no structure or sub-components. Again `int` is a good example, but `string` has sub-components (the different characters from which it is built). Another non-primitive type would be `file`, as this has some structure like a file name or path.